# "Multiple markers at this line"

Tags: java, gwt

I'm following the [Stockwatcher](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/create.html) tutorial.

When I try to run it I'm getting this error?: "Multiple markers at this line" (I have added a comment in that line below).

```
package com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyCodes;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressHandler;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.NumberFormat;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HorizontalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Random;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StockWatcher implements EntryPoint {

  private static final int REFRESH_INTERVAL = 5000;
  private VerticalPanel mainPanel = new VerticalPanel();
  private FlexTable stocksFlexTable = new FlexTable();
  private HorizontalPanel addPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
  private TextBox newSymbolTextBox = new TextBox();
  private Button addStockButton = new Button("Add");
  private Label lastUpdatedLabel = new Label();
  private ArrayList<String> stocks = new ArrayList<String>();

  /**
   * Entry point method.
   */
  public void onModuleLoad() {

    // Create table for stock data.
    stocksFlexTable.setText(0, 0, "Symbol");
    stocksFlexTable.setText(0, 1, "Price");
    stocksFlexTable.setText(0, 2, "Change");
    stocksFlexTable.setText(0, 3, "Remove");  

    // Assemble Add Stock panel.
    addPanel.add(newSymbolTextBox);
    addPanel.add(addStockButton);

    // Assemble Main panel.
    mainPanel.add(stocksFlexTable);
    mainPanel.add(addPanel);
    mainPanel.add(lastUpdatedLabel);

    // Associate the Main panel with the HTML host page.
    RootPanel.get("stockList").add(mainPanel);    

    // Move cursor focus to the input box.
    newSymbolTextBox.setFocus(true);

    // Setup timer to refresh list automatically.
    Timer refreshTimer = new Timer() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        refreshWatchList();
      }

    };
    refreshTimer.scheduleRepeating(REFRESH_INTERVAL); //THIS IS THE LINE OF THE 

    // Listen for mouse events on the Add button.
    addStockButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
      public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        addStock();
      }
    });

    // Listen for keyboard events in the input box.
    newSymbolTextBox.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
      public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
          System.out.println("foo=" + KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER);
          System.out.println("bar=" + (int)event.getCharCode());
        if (event.getCharCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {


          addStock();
        }
      }
    });

  }

  /**
   * Add stock to FlexTable. Executed when the user clicks the addStockButton or
   * presses enter in the newSymbolTextBox.
   */
  private void addStock() {
    final String symbol = newSymbolTextBox.getText().toUpperCase().trim();
    newSymbolTextBox.setFocus(true);

    // Stock code must be between 1 and 10 chars that are numbers, letters, or dots.
    if (!symbol.matches("^[0-9A-Z\\.]{1,10}$")) {
      Window.alert("'" + symbol + "' is not a valid symbol.");
      newSymbolTextBox.selectAll();
      return;
    }

    newSymbolTextBox.setText("");

    // Don't add the stock if it's already in the table.
    if (stocks.contains(symbol))
      return;

    // Add the stock to the table.
    int row = stocksFlexTable.getRowCount();
    stocks.add(symbol);
    stocksFlexTable.setText(row, 0, symbol);

    // Add a button to remove this stock from the table.
    Button removeStockButton = new Button("x");
    removeStockButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
      public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        int removedIndex = stocks.indexOf(symbol);
        stocks.remove(removedIndex);        stocksFlexTable.removeRow(removedIndex + 1);
      }
    });
    stocksFlexTable.setWidget(row, 3, removeStockButton);

    // Get the stock price.
    refreshWatchList();

  }

  private void refreshWatchList() {
    final double MAX_PRICE = 100.0; // $100.00
    final double MAX_PRICE_CHANGE = 0.02; // +/- 2%

    StockPrice[] prices = new StockPrice[stocks.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < stocks.size(); i++) {
      double price = Random.nextDouble() * MAX_PRICE;
      double change = price * MAX_PRICE_CHANGE
          * (Random.nextDouble() * 2.0 - 1.0);

      prices[i] = new StockPrice(stocks.get(i), price, change);
    }

    updateTable(prices);

  }

  /**
   * Update the Price and Change fields all the rows in the stock table.
   *
   * @param prices Stock data for all rows.
   */
  private void updateTable(StockPrice[] prices) {
    for (int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
        updateTable(prices[i]);
      }
  }

  /**
   * Update a single row in the stock table.
   *
   * @param price Stock data for a single row.
   */
  private void updateTable(StockPrice price) {
    // Make sure the stock is still in the stock table.
    if (!stocks.contains(price.getSymbol())) {
      return;
    }

    int row = stocks.indexOf(price.getSymbol()) + 1;

    // Format the data in the Price and Change fields.
    String priceText = NumberFormat.getFormat("#,##0.00").format(
        price.getPrice());
    NumberFormat changeFormat = NumberFormat.getFormat("+#,##0.00;-#,##0.00");
    String changeText = changeFormat.format(price.getChange());
    String changePercentText = changeFormat.format(price.getChangePercent());

    // Populate the Price and Change fields with new data.
    stocksFlexTable.setText(row, 1, priceText);
    stocksFlexTable.setText(row, 2, changeText + " (" + changePercentText
        + "%)");
  }

}
```

This is the stack of errors:

```
StockWatcher [Web Application]  
    com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode at localhost:56938   
        Thread [main] (Running) 
        Thread [Thread-1] (Running) 
        Daemon Thread [Thread-2] (Running)  
        Daemon Thread [UnitWriteThread] (Running)   
        Daemon Thread [Timer-0] (Running)   
        Daemon Thread [Code server listener] (Running)  
        Daemon Thread [com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.base.internal.Finalizer] (Running)    
        Thread [2048426764@qtp-774727454-1 - Acceptor0 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8888] (Running)   
        Thread [2108438076@qtp-774727454-0] (Running)   
        Daemon Thread [Timer-1] (Running)   
        Daemon Thread [Code server for stockwatcher from Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1 on http://127.0.0.1:8888/StockWatcher.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 @ 1hS?FL4(4E4"'T^J] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 67 in StockWatcher))   
            StockWatcher.onModuleLoad() line: 67    
            NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
            NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 57  
            DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 43  
            Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 601  
            ModuleSpaceOOPHM(ModuleSpace).onLoad(TreeLogger) line: 396  
            OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(BrowserChannelServer, String, String, String, String, String, byte[]) line: 200  
            BrowserChannelServer.processConnection() line: 525  
            BrowserChannelServer.run() line: 363    
            Thread.run() line: 722  
    /usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_01/bin/java (Nov 22, 2011 12:45:50 PM)
```

Javi

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?  If so, 'Multiple Markers ...' is Eclipse's way of telling you that there are multiple errors on that line.  Try refreshing the project folder and doing a build - it could just be Eclipse being special.

Comment: @mcfinnigan, yes I'm using Eclipse. I selected the project and then refreshed it but the error is the same... I would like to build it as you say but I can't find that action and I'm not sure if that would solve my problem because till now I didn't see anythink related to building the Stockwatcher app...

Comment: @mcfinnigan, well I found the build option, but it's not active even when I select the project from the explorer. "Build automatically" is activated.

Comment: ^B is usually the Eclipse build command - otherwise, select Project / Clean after making sure Project / Build Automatically is checked.  Also, open Window / Show View / Problems and you should get a list of current compilation errors in your workspace.

Comment: @mcfinnigan, I don't see anything at my Problems window. The errors for me are showed at Show view / Development mode.

Comment: Can you obtain a list of the errors in any way?

Comment: @mcfinnigan, I've pasted them in my question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5231/discussion-between-tirengarfio-and-mcfinnigan)

Comment: Try to delete the folder that GWT creates after compilation in war directory, then redeploy.

Comment: This is not the s'tack of errors'. This is a listing of what happened at runtime when you *ran* it. We are looking for compilation errors here.

Answer (score 0):

Your list of error does not communicate much. It just says "(Suspended (breakpoint at line 67 in StockWatcher))" which is you manually stopping the process. Let if fail and paste that.

In any case, I see no issues in the specific line. One thing that can mess up the compiler is an extra `(` or `{`, else, try cleaning the project, erasing the GWT-generated code and rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple markers is nothing but if there is more than one wrong with the line what you have been coded".

The main problem is that you are trying to insert more than one statements are directly into a class, constructor, method etc...,